# How to place response in inputs angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I would like to put data received into my 3 inputs. I receive json response from my node server and the controller should receive the response and place it into my 3 inputs.
I receive a response but I can't place it in inputs

**Controller:**

```
$scope.edit = function(id, contact) {
console.log(id);
$http.get('/contactlist/' + id).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  $scope.contact = response;
});
};
```

**Server:**

```
app.get('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res) {
 var id = req.params.id;
console.log(id);
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM contactlist WHERE id = ' + id, function (error, results, fields) {
   console.log(results);
   res.json(results);
   });
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<div class="input-field col s4">
    <input id="name" type="text" class="form" ng-model="contact.name">
    <label for="name">Nom</label>
    {{contact.name}}
</div>
<div class="input-field col s4">
    <input id="email" type="text" class="form" ng-model="contact.email">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s4">
    <input id="number" type="text" class="form" ng-model="contact.number">
    <label for="number">Numéro</label>
</div>
```

**The response received on chrome :** 
[response from chrome object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO7SF.png)

Comment: what does console.log prints ?

Comment: What does `response` look like when you log it? It should probably be `$scope.contact = response.data`

Comment: Change  $scope.contact = response; to  $scope.contact = response.data;

Comment: @tymeJV I gave you a screenshot , I edited the post

Comment: I recommend you change your serverside to only return one result, not an array. That's the general convention when the endpoint includes an ID. That's assuming you only expect one result from the db naturally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the $http service, the resolved object in the `then` function contains the full response. The response object doesn't just contain your data, it also contains properties such as statusCode and the config used when sending the request. So what you want to do instead is this:

```
$http.get('/contactlist/' + id).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  $scope.contact = response.data;
});
```

Note the use of `response.data` rater than just `response`. Also, note that serverside, you'd probably want to only return the first result - not the array of results:

```
app.get('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM contactlist WHERE id = ' + id, function (error, results, fields) {
        console.log(results);
        res.json(results[0]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I accept your response cause this is the solution that I use actually, and you helped me to understand data objects reception thanks a lot

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

your response has data array with object. data[0] has contact object.

```
$http.get('/contactlist/' + id).then(function(response) {  
  $scope.contact = response.data[0];
});
```

Comment: Nice, thank, problem solved !
Thank you verymuch for all  of your responses

Answer (score 0):

Since you receive a list of contacts, I'd suggest you'd do this:

```
$http.get('/contactlist/' + id).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  $scope.contacts = response.data; //note the 's'
});
```

And in html

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <input id="name" type="text" class="form" ng-model="contact.name">
      <label for="name">Nom</label>
      {{contact.name}}
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <input id="email" type="text" class="form" ng-model="contact.email">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <input id="number" type="text" class="form" ng-model="contact.number">
      <label for="number">Numéro</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a directive for this: ng-repeat="contact in contactlist"
Cause I don't need repeat inputs.
I repeat this: {{contact.name}} &.email & .number